# How to install github library without `devtools`

Tags: r, github, installation

Let's say I wanted to install a library off of github without devtools.  How would I do that?

I was helping a student in office hours today, and devtools required a lot of dependencies.  It took nearly a half-an-hour just to get him ready to use it.  I know that `install.packages` works for local files, is the github setup going to enable this?

Let's say: `https://github.com/laresbernardo/lares`

I understand that `devtools::install_github` is just a wrapper for `remote::install_github` which explains some of the dependency issues with these packages (and tidyverse in general - `haven` was broken today for Windoze).

Can I not install a package directly using `install.packages` from `R:base` using the remote source?

Comment: Packages on github are basically just the source code for packages. They are generally not compiled (built) in the way they need to be for use with `install.packages`. You need to have the proper build environment set up to make that happen. As you already pointed out, you can just use `remotes::install_github` without installing `devtools`. That will be a lot easier assuming the package you are trying to install doesn't require compiling c or c++ code.

Comment: You can build the package outside of R if you really want to. You could clone the repo. Then at the command line run `R CMD BUILD` to built the package. And then `R CMD INSTALL` to install it. See https://kbroman.org/pkg_primer/pages/build.html. but you can't do that directly from github. You'd need to do the clone yourself (which is what remotes does for you)

Comment: I can likely download the "zip" file and extract with my own code base.

Comment: Sure. You could download the zip rather than do a clone. You'll still need to unzip it, build it (which will create a tar.gz file), then install it.

Comment: I need to dig into `remotes` because this `R CMD BUILD` is likely possible using a shell script of some sort.